# Puppet and Intel Fortran install.sh

Tags: bash, sh, puppet, intel-fortran

I'm trying to install the Intel Fortran compiler (parallel_studio_xe_2016_composer_edition_for_fortran_update4) package via puppet. Usually you want to do this by using the install.sh script that comes with the package. I set up a silent.cfg file to install in noninteractive mode. When I run

```
./install.sh --silent /path/to/silent.cfg
```

on the client it works fine as well. However if I execute via puppet like this (adapted from https://git.101010.fr/puppet/ifort/)

```
exec { "Install ifort":
command     => "/path/to/install.sh --silent /path/to/silent.cfg",
environment => 'USER=root',
creates     => "/opt/intel/bin/ifort",
path        => [ '/bin', '/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'],
onlyif      => "test -f /path/to/silent.cfg",
}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
/install.sh: line 786: 32566 Aborted (core dumped) "$pset_engine_cli_binary" --TEMP_FOLDER="$temp_folder" $params
```

I wonder if anyone is deploying recent ifort versions via puppet as well. My guess is that the environmet of the bash is somehow different from what puppet is supplying, but from the error message I have no clue what this might be.

Comment: Start by looking at everything that is different from you executing the script manually versus executing with Puppet. For example, you are manually executing the script from the same directory as the script, but you are not doing that with Puppet. Use the `cwd` attribute for that. Then, go from there with debugging.

Comment: True I added cwd, but this does not change anything, since it installs with /path/to/Intel.sh .. on the client as well.

Comment: I guess I have to ask over at Intel what kind of environment variables the install script uses, because this will be what differs.

Comment: For anyone facing the same issue: I went over to deploying Fortran via RPM package, seems to be a more puppety way anyways